# Zoom in an object when that contain reaching at center of window - jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm posting a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/HWzz3/3/
This is the situation. I want to scale or zoom the container when it comes to vertical-center on the window. and back to its original when it is not at that position or scrolled out of that position. Is it possible with jquery?

```
<div id="container">My content</div>
```

I will try than zooming in when coming to center and zooming out when going away from the center. Any idea or help?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HWzz3/4/)*

```
var contPos = $('#container').position().top;
var conthH = $('#container').height()/2;

$(window).on('scroll resize', function(){
    var scr = $(this).scrollTop(),
        winH = $(this).height()/2,
        curr = Math.abs((scr+winH)-(contPos+conthH)),  
        size = (curr<150)  ?  500:200   ;
    $('#container').stop(1).animate({width:size, height:size, marginTop:-size/2},300);   
});
```

You'll see a `size = (curr<150)  ?  500:200   ;` 
`150` means a 'screen center zone' in px to do something (you can play with that value as desired)
white `500` and `200` are the **MAX** and **MIN** sizes you want to apply.

Comment: Thanks for the code ! It works well. But a problem. This doesn't work with more than one block. Like there is a sequence of elements like that. The one in center should zoom in. That doesn't seem to work. I couldn't figure it out how to do it. http://jsfiddle.net/HWzz3/5/

Comment: @user1820644 ok right now I have no time to take a closer look, but I surely will. Just a tip: next time try to be more specific immediately in your question, Cause a house , and a house without electricity are not the same :)